# How to insert Character as well as Integer value in a column of MySQL server 5.5?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert integer as well as character value in same column depend on condition But I don't know which datatype i need to use....

Answer (score 3):

The data type you need to use is `VARCHAR` because you can still insert string representation of an integer on that column. But if you choose to use `INT`, you can't insert a string on it.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
    columnName VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('a'); -- OK
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('1'); -- OK
```

both queries will be inserted on the table.

in the case you'll use `INT`

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
    columnName INT
);

INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (1); -- OK
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('a'); -- FAILED
```

the tendency is that you can't store string.

Comment: **NOTE**: If `sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'` is not set then: `INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('a');` in second table will cause insert value of 0 in `columnName`

Answer (score 1):

you can use any string data type according to requirement

```
( char, varchar )
```

but  don't forgot to enclose them in single quotes

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('1One');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use varchar, all of these will produce the effect you want:

```
INSERT INTO atul (c1) values ('a');
INSERT INTO atul (c1) values ('1');
INSERT INTO atul (c1) values (1);
```

Comment: In MySQL it does, but in SQL Server it will fail with this error.. `Schema Creation Failed: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int`... given `a` is the first record entering into your table column declared as `varchar`

Comment: the question is tagged as mysql

Comment: It is also tagged in `SQL` ;) well you got it mate. The thing is it's best to encourage the `standard varchar` data insert :)

Comment: I believe that the OP wants to insert an actual integer, not the char representation of one. 1 is not the same as '1'. That's why I pointed out the case. Otherwise, you're just inserting chars ('1' is ascii 49 same as 'a' is ascii '97'). I think the tricky bit of the question was the data type he wants to insert.

Comment: Now that is a much acceptable comment. +1 for that last insert case. I tried out it works with `SELECT CAST(c1 AS UNSIGNED INT) FROM table1 where id = 2` nothing fails. It also works with any string functions as well.. like `substr`, `instr`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `varchar` type for that field.

For example:

```
create table volt_meter(
    voltage varchar(5);
)

INSERT into volt_meter values('11kv');
```